# Why the vertex is still acting theweired even after I flip the normal to right

Tags: vertices, bevel

[image]

Has anyone encountered a similar issue where face orientation is unified, and normals are in the same direction, but it acts creepy when you try to bevel the vertex? Please help fix the problem.

Comment: please share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com. also try `a` to select all vertices then `m` > merge by distance

Comment: I am sorry; it was fixed automatically after merging the distance. I did that so many times, which didn't work out. But this morning. I open the file again and merge it again. it fixed.  I thought it was some normal issue. I had no idea that It was just a glitch.